# jquery ajax passing 2 arrays and then split them and use them separetely in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, laravel

When i change the value of a dropdown list in a view, i pass it with an ajax call in a controller to return 2 arrays to change 2 other dropdown lists in the same view in laravel.

The controller code is:

```
public function CreatGegCityAjax($id)
{        
    $offices = \App\office::where("city_id",$id)->orderBy('name','asc')->get()->pluck('name','id');
    $chars = \App\Char::where("city_id",$id)->orderBy('name','asc')->get()->pluck('name','id');

    return json_encode(array('offices' => "$offices",'chars' => "$chars"));
}
```

The code in the view is

```
$('select[name="city_id"]').on('change', function() {
        var cityID = $(this).val();

        if(cityID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/admin/gegonos/ajax/city/'+cityID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",                    
                success:function(data) {   

                $('select[name="office_id"]').empty();

                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                   $('select[name="office_id"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value.offices +'</option>');
                });    

                $('select[name="char_id"]').empty();

                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                   $('select[name="char_id"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value.chars +'</option>');
                });    
                }                    
            });
        }else{
            $('select[name="office_id"]').empty();
            $('select[name="char_id"]').empty();
        }
    });
```

This works with no error but it doesnt get values in the dropdown lists. It shows  'undefined'.
How can i split the values of json data using each array in the right dropdown list?
Thanks

Comment: Please update the question with the result of `console.log(data)` in your ajax success callback function

Comment: where exactly to put console.log(data)?

Comment: In `success:function(data) { `

Comment: i put it and shows offices: [] chars: []

Comment: It means the `$offices` and `$chars` in your eloquent query returns nothing

Comment: so how can i split them after to use the values of the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```
return response()->json(['offices'=>$offices, 'chars'=>$chars]);
```

See here about Laravel json response: http://coursesweb.net/laravel/responses#anc_jre

- Then, put `console.log(data)` in the `success:function` to see received response in console, and parse it according to its structure.

Comment: using this returns 
    offices: [object Object]
    chars: [object Object]

Comment: Thank you very much your answer helped me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you receive `json` response from the controller in the format as

```
{
'offices' : {
        '1' : 'name',
        '2' : 'name'
    },
'chars': {
        '1' : 'name',
        '2' : 'name'
    }
}
```

you would need to change your success callback function as

```
success: function(data) {

    $('select[name="office_id"]').empty();

    if (Object.keys(data.offices).length) {

        $.each(data.offices, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="office_id"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
        });

    }

    $('select[name="char_id"]').empty();

    if (Object.keys(data.chars).length) {

        $.each(data.chars, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="char_id"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
        }); 

    }

}
```